# Laravel add custom attribute to paginate result

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pagination, attributes, customization

I'm trying to add some data into the paginate result.
This is the code:

```
// query select and filter
[...]

$totalAmount = $sales->sum('amount');
$result = $sales->paginate($rowsPerPage);
return $result;
```

The result is:

```
{
    "datatable": {
        "current_page": 1,
        "data": [
            {
                "sale": 13047689,
                "customer": "0017850000104",
                "date": "2015-12-23 23:15:06",
                "amount": "129.84",
            }
        ],
        "first_page_url": "http://intranet/api/user/sales/datatable?custom=value&page=1",
        "from": 1,
        "last_page": 1,
        "last_page_url": "http://intranet/api/user/sales/datatable?custom=value&page=1",
        "next_page_url": null,
        "path": "http://intranet/api/user/sales/datatable",
        "per_page": "10",
        "prev_page_url": null,
        "to": 1,
        "total": 1
    }
}
```

I'd like to add the totalAmount into this paginate object.

What I tried:

```
$result->appends('totalAmount', $totalAmount);
```

I find this method over internet but seems it does nothing... The result is exactly like the above without this attribute.

Another method I found is put.

```
$result->put('totalAmount', $totalAmount);
```

This method really works but not the way I need. This is for add some rows to the result because it adds the attribute inside "data". This breaks my code when I pass this results for datatable.

```
{
    "datatable": {
        "current_page": 1,
        "data": {
            "0": {
                "sale": 13047689,
                "customer": "0017850000104",
                "date": "2015-12-23 23:15:06",
                "amount": "129.84",
            },
            "totalAmount": "129.84"
        },
        "first_page_url": "http://intranet/api/user/sales/datatable?page=1",
        "from": 1,
        "last_page": 1,
        "last_page_url": "http://intranet/api/user/sales/datatable?page=1",
        "next_page_url": null,
        "path": "http://intranet/api/user/sales/datatable",
        "per_page": "10",
        "prev_page_url": null,
        "to": 2,
        "total": 1
    }
}
```

How can I do it???

I'd like this:

```
{
    "datatable": {
        "current_page": 1,
        "data": [
            {
                "sale": 13047689,
                "customer": "0017850000104",
                "date": "2015-12-23 23:15:06",
                "amount": "129.84",
            }
        ],
        "first_page_url": "http://intranet/api/user/sales/datatable?page=1",
        "from": 1,
        "last_page": 1,
        "last_page_url": "http://intranet/api/user/sales/datatable?page=1",
        "next_page_url": null,
        "path": "http://intranet/api/user/sales/datatable",
        "per_page": "10",
        "prev_page_url": null,
        "to": 2,
        "total": 1,
        "totalAmount": "129.84"
    }
}
```

Or the further step would be:

```
{
    "datatable": {
        "current_page": 1,
        "data": [
            {
                "sale": 13047689,
                "customer": "0017850000104",
                "date": "2015-12-23 23:15:06",
                "amount": "129.84",
            }
        ],
        "first_page_url": "http://intranet/api/user/sales/datatable?page=1",
        "from": 1,
        "last_page": 1,
        "last_page_url": "http://intranet/api/user/sales/datatable?page=1",
        "next_page_url": null,
        "path": "http://intranet/api/user/sales/datatable",
        "per_page": "10",
        "prev_page_url": null,
        "to": 2,
        "total": 1,
        "totalData": {
            "accumulated1": 235,
            "accumulated2": 799,
            "accumulated3": 1680,
        },
    }
}
```

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you need to create resource for your response first, then add meta data to result like this:

```
return (new UserCollection(User::all()->load('roles')))
                ->additional(['meta' => [
                    'key' => 'value',
                ]]);
```

---

[check this out](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources#adding-meta-data)

Answer (score 1):

In case that you need it for a paginator result, you must implement the corresponding two Resources:

```
namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\PaginatedResourceResponse;

class CustomizablePaginatedResourceResponse extends PaginatedResourceResponse
{

    /**
     * Custom attributes.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected array $attrs = [];

    /**
     * Add the pagination information to the response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     */
    protected function paginationInformation($request): array
    {
        $paginated = $this->resource->resource->toArray();
        $paginated['meta'] = $this->attrs;

        return $paginated;
    }


    /**
     * Add attributes.
     *
     * @param array $attrs
     * @return $this
     */
    public function addAttributes(array $attrs): static
    {
        $this->attrs = $attrs;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

and

```
namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;
use Illuminate\Pagination\AbstractPaginator;


class CustomizablePaginatedResource extends ResourceCollection
{

    /**
     * Custom attributes.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected array $attrs = [];

    /**
     * Create an HTTP response that represents the object.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function toResponse($request)
    {
        if (!($this->resource instanceof AbstractPaginator)) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Only AbstractPaginator is accepted');
        }

        return (new CustomizablePaginatedResourceResponse($this))
            ->addAttributes($this->attrs)
            ->toResponse($request);
    }


    /**
     * Add custom attribute.
     *
     * @param string $key
     * @param mixed $value
     * @return $this
     */
    public function addAttribute(string $key, mixed $value): static
    {
        $this->attrs[$key] = $value;
        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * Remove attribute.
     *
     * @param string $key
     * @return $this
     */
    public function delAttribute(string $key): static
    {
        unset($this->attrs[$key]);
        return $this;
    }

}
```

Now in you controller you have enclose the pagination instance into the into the resource like in the following example:

```
return (new CustomizablePaginatedResource($qry->paginate()))
            ->addAttribute('my_attribute1', 'foo')
            ->addAttribute('my_attribute2', 'bar');
```

The pagination will add the attributes into the "meta" attribute located in the root. Feel free to customize the resource in order to change the root attribute name.

Answer (score 0):

Please try just with

```
$result->totalAmount = $totalAmount;
```

And then to access it just use `$result->totalAmount;`.
It's just an object, there shouldn't be any problems

Comment: This works, but when the controller returns the result with json format the attribute disappears: `return response()->json(['datatable' => $sales], 200);`

Comment: So in ste serialization that field disappear?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$totalAmount = $sales->sum('amount');
$result = $sales->paginate($rowsPerPage);

$custom = collect(['totalAmount' => $totalAmount]);

$data = $custom->merge($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured this out. If you are trying to return a json or array result, just change the paginated data to an array first. Then add the attributes you need to the array.

```
$results = $data->paginate()->toArray();
$results['new_attribute'] = 'Attribute Value';
return response()->json($result);
```

Merging or appending to the paginated data doesn't work because it gets lost when converted to an array.

Answer (score 0):

First, you perform pagination on your $sales query:

```
$result = $sales->paginate($rowsPerPage);
```

Then, you convert the result to an array:

```
$result = $result->toArray();
```

Next, you add your attribute:

$result['totalAmount'] = $sales->sum('amount');

```
 return $result;
```

In summary, you perform pagination on the $sales query, convert the result to an array, add the totalAmount attribute by calculating the sum of the amount field from the original $sales query, and then return the modified result.

Please note that you should replace $rowsPerPage with the actual value for the number of rows per page, and adjust the code to fit your specific use case.